# Flutter change padding area background color

Tags: flutter, padding

I have ListTile inside padding. I need to change the padding area color. How can I change it?[image]

```dart
SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                  (context, index) => Card(
                elevation: 1,
                color: MyColors.white,
                margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: ListTile(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
                        tileColor: Color(0xFFFCF9E8),
                        leading: Image(image: AssetImage(_allUsers[index]['icon']),height: 30,width: 30,),
                        title: Text(_allUsers[index]['name']),
                        subtitle: Text('${_allUsers[index]["generic"]}'),
                        trailing: Text('${_allUsers[index]["unit_price"]}'),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              childCount: _allUsers.length,
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Container` instead of `Padding` and give padding and color to it like this:

```dart
Container(
                color: Colors.red, //color
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0), //your padding 
                child:ListTile(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
                        tileColor: Color(0xFFFCF9E8),
                        leading: Image(image: AssetImage(_allUsers[index]['icon']),height: 30,width: 30,),
                        title: Text(_allUsers[index]['name']),
                        subtitle: Text('${_allUsers[index]["generic"]}'),
                        trailing: Text('${_allUsers[index]["unit_price"]}'),
              ),
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ColoredBox` for that:

```
ColoredBox(
  color: MyColors.white,
  child:SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                  (context, index) => Card(
                elevation: 1,
                color: MyColors.white,
                margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: ListTile(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
                        tileColor: Color(0xFFFCF9E8),
                        leading: Image(image: AssetImage(_allUsers[index]['icon']),height: 30,width: 30,),
                        title: Text(_allUsers[index]['name']),
                        subtitle: Text('${_allUsers[index]["generic"]}'),
                        trailing: Text('${_allUsers[index]["unit_price"]}'),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              childCount: _allUsers.length,
            ),
          ),
  ),
```